# how to fix ssh-copy-id connection timed out error?

Tags: server, ssh, login

I logged in Following the steps to automate ssh login ends up with disconnecting from server.

```
# ssh-keygen
# ssh-copy-id userid@hostname -p 2242
# 
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: "/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed

/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: ssh: connect to host userid@hostname port 2242: Connection timed out
```

I don't know it didn't complete importing the keys to the server.

Comment: That's what [ssh keys](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys) are for. Each user should have a separate account, and separate keys. Adding accounts is trivial - NEVER share accounts (except the Guest account, of course). "Without knowledge" implies hiding your presence from other users...please edit your question to explain the legitimate purpose of such activity.

Comment: Yes. Read `man ssh-copy-id`, and use it to copy YOUR public key to the Target User's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

Comment: @user535733 You mean **we** keep logging to the same user but differently, i.e., I have automated logging but he hasn't'?

Comment: @user535733 By "without knowledge" I meant without affecting other user's access. I don't have to automate his access. I want to keep the same password but automate my own access only.

Comment: Enabling key-based access does not turn off password-based access. You can use both at the same time.

Comment: To clarify – ssh actually allows you to specify which authentication methods are allowed.  You *can* turn off password-based access if you choose, and so on.

Comment: @Student404Mus Consider using ssh keys. Everything else will be dirty.